# What exactly does "attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor" mean in case of CC-BY-SA

Tags: creative-commons, attribution, cc-by-sa, wikipedia

In case I'm about to use an image from Wikimedia Commons (like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sa-warthog.jpg for example), what exactly does

> attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor

mean? There is hardly ever any exact formulation that the autor requires except for the generic CC block.

Would this be sufficient?

> Image [Sa-warthog.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sa-warthog.jpg) is part of Wikimedia Commons licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Creative Commons wiki best practices page](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution) suggests that a good attribution includes the title, author, source and license of the material. If there is no format specified you can't miss if you follow those basic rules.

In your case the title is: "A soiled Warthog relaxing during a hot day at San Diego Zoo, California, USA"
The author: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Sanjay_ach
The source is the link you provided
And the license is CC-BY-SA 3.0

Comment: That means that I should at least display the user name somehow, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the right thing to do unless the author has specifically asked not to be named